# When is disk fragmentation an issue and how does one fix it?

Tags: partitioning, ext4

My `ext4` drive recently filled up to 95 percent capacity before I cleared out space on my disk. While transferring files from my computer to an external hard drive, I noticed a lot of my oldest media transferred fairly quickly, while some of the newer material was copying at a much slower rate. (It also seemed to stall or pause often.) Could this be due to fragmentation? If so, what is the optimal solution for maintaining good disk health?

Comment: I hope you are not confusing old files with large files and new ones with small ones: many small files take a lot of time to be transferred while large ones transfer faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you have too much disk space in use, ext4 cannot defrag that well so you will suffer from fragmentation at the end of the drive. Furthermore, when you write data to a hard drive, writes start at the outermost part of the magnetic platters which are faster than the innermost part at the end of the drive.

I would recommend using btrfs with compress=lzo as a mount option to both shrink the size of your compressible data and speed up transfer rates. I wouldn't recommend using Ext4 anymore considering it is slower than both Btrfs and XFS.